# How to calculate ALL modes in a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set (`11,11,14,14,10`).

My goal is to return all frequently appeared numbers. I used `=mode()` function.

But, it does not return `11` and `14`, only returns `11`.

Any ideas/thoughts on that?

Comment: In Excel 2010+ there is an additional function called `MODE.MULT` which accomplishes this, however I don't think it is available in Google Sheets yet i.e. only `MODE.SNGL` is available, so you will need to do a more custom approach like the one used in the answer by @pnuts.

Comment: Yeah, it is so much easier with mode.mult in excel. Since I don't have a license to use it google sheets is my number one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With layout as shown,

```
=query(A2:A6,"select count(A), A group by A order by count(A) desc label count(A) 'frequency'")
```

should return a listing of all frequencies in descending order:

[image: SO54279058 example]

Comment: this query returns frequency but not the numbers that appear frequently. How would I get 11 and 14 instead of 2,2,1?

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:A, "select count(A), A 
                    group by A 
                    order by count(A) desc"),
                   "select Col2 where Col1 > 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(E1:1), "select *"),
                                              "select count(Col1), Col1 
                                               group by Col1 
                                               order by count(Col1) desc"),
                                              "select Col2 where Col1 > 1", 0))
```

[image: 4]