# Making a Top 3 column based on a column category with answers in the row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm managing the server awards for a gaming community and using Google Forms for the first time. The voting phase ended, I moved the form responses into an excel sheet in Google Docs.

It goes like this (**Answers from 89 forum accounts [ROWS] for 31 questions [COLUMNS]**)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKQSW.png)

The nominations were put as multiple-choice votes in the Forms as can be seen here, if this helps at all.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaBCL.png)

Most of the attempts I've read on the internet read back to integer values, whereas I'm using strings. Plus, I really have no idea how to work formulas on Excel.

I need the results to be like this, if possible.

**Name One** —> Most repeated name in Column C, from Row 2 to Row 30.

**(47)** —> Amount of times Name One is repeated in Column C.

Name Two and Three show us the second and third most repeated names.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQRqQ.png)

Comment: From Review: You stated something that you wanted to do. But you haven't actually asked a question. Have you tried to accomplish your goal? What prevented you from accomplishing it? Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example showing your attempt?

Comment: You talk about both Excel and Google Sheets. Which are you using, or do you not care which? Also, here's the link for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is missing in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you are using Google Sheets

To get your top **three** in column **C**, add this formula into another sheet.

```
=QUERY('Your sheet name'!A1:Z100,
// Change the sheet name and the last cell reference to suit.
// Keep the single quotes around the sheet name if it has a
// space or a non-alphanumeric character in it.

"Select C, count(C) group by C order by count(C) desc limit 3")
```

Thanks to @pnuts's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54279562/7498443) on another question for allowing me to double check without turning on my laptop. :)

---

Have tested it and it's working for me.

[image: Change example]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I'm still getting a parse error. :(
https://i.imgur.com/3D8LAlV.png

Comment: Did you take out the comments in the formula? (The lines beginning with `//`)

Comment: Yeah, I did that obviously. :c

Comment: It's working for me. I have added an example in my answer.

Comment: I'm not getting the accurate results. I'm not sure what it's calculating at this point. What its doing right now is listing the last 3 names in the list alphabetically (https://i.imgur.com/eFLheqC.png) (https://i.imgur.com/zAJ23SY.png). It's not counting the votes exactly.

Comment: Nothing to do with that image. I have made my answer clearer. I mentioned a change that should be made to correct the order, but it was at the bottom of my answer and you mustn't have seen it.